# Ionic/angular provider/service - singleton - single instance?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have read that service(angular)/provider(ionic) can be specific to components, or can be shared by components by registering it at module level. I understand that this is singleton concept that is single instance shared by all components. My question is - suppose the service/provider has code that fetches data from db based on logged in userid, then in this case, how does a single instance concept differentiate between all users using the app? Bit confused on this aspect.

Comment: ionic1 angularjs ?

Comment: Client code is executed on client machine so there is sort of only one user at a time (client code itself is “instanced” per user), so singleton for a client code is just a further concept WITHIN client instance.

Answer (score 0):

As far As i know **singleton** means a single component/service that have content that can be shared with any other page/component/controller/...
but all that is happening in one instance of the app.

Example: 
lets say in our project we have 3 pages with controllers: `page1.html, ctrl1.js`, `page2.html, ctrl2.js`, `page3.html, ctrl3.js`

We also have 1 service: `service1.js`

In `service1.js` we have a function called `getUserName()`

The concept of singleton will allow `getUserName()` to be called from all 3 controllers. if the service is not sigleton this means it will be related to one controller/page, so if service1.js is only related to ctrl1.js, the function `getUserName()` cannot be called from ctrl2.js

**Important**: all this is happening in one instance of the app, singleton does not mean that the service is **SHARED** between all running instances of the app.

That being said, if you are using your service to get data from the database based on some parameters, it is the logic you implemented that decide what data will be returned.